# Codeigniter bad system folder path

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I've installed CodeIgniter into `/usr/share/pear/codeigniter`. If I set in my app's `index.php`

```
$system_path = '/usr/share/pear/codeigniter/system';
```

it works everything well.

But when I `mount --bind` or copy to `/pub/codeigniter`, and set `$system_path` to `/pub/codeigniter/system`, doesn't work and CI displays an error message:

```
Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php
```

The permissions:

```
$ ls -ld /usr/share/pear/codeigniter/{,*}
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 febr  17 13.07 /usr/share/pear/codeigniter/
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4096 febr  17 13.07 /usr/share/pear/codeigniter/application
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 6357 febr  17 13.07 /usr/share/pear/codeigniter/index.php
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 febr  17 13.07 /usr/share/pear/codeigniter/system

$ ls -ld /pub/codeigniter/{,*}
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 júl   15 13.20 /pub/codeigniter/
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4096 febr  17 13.07 /pub/codeigniter/application
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 6357 febr  17 13.07 /pub/codeigniter/index.php
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 júl   15 13.20 /pub/codeigniter/system
```

I think the PHP's `is_dir` function fails but I don't know why.

Any suggestion?

Comment: have you tried to call `is_dir` yourself to check?

Comment: In `index.php` there is an `is_dir` check: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/index.php#L191 `var_dump(is_dir($system_path))` prints `bool(false)`. `$system_path` stores right value (`echo $system_path` prints good output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault: in `/etc/php/php.ini` should add `/pub` to `open_basedir`'s list, restart webserver and everything will fine.